# 2nd instance of mysql closes/doesnt start no warnings/errors?

Tags: mysql

I have an external HD and i'd like to run a 2nd mysql instance on it. I used the windows installer to install/configure mysqld as a service on windows7. I took the my.ini from

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
```

Then edited the port (client and mysqld), datadir and innodb_data_home_dir. After running this command

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="f:/dev/my.ini"
```

I found an error which was all about the innodb_data_home_dir directory not existing. After that I ran the command again. Mysqld simply starts up for a second then immediately closes. I see no message in my command prompt. I know this command line args are correct as i see the mysqld service using the same one except a different my.ini path. Also it did tell me about the directory not existing so i know it is reading the new ini file.

How do i figure out why this 2nd instance of mysqld is closing? How do i get 2 instance running?

I'm using v 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Mysql documentation is idiotic and their packaging is lacking (it is missing mysql_install_db). I have to download mysql-5.5.28-win32.zip (careful not mysql-5.5.28.zip under windows 32. Its source which is not mentioned at all) then copy performance_schema/ and mysql/ to the data directory THEN mysqld can run...